# Magento DEBUG (7): Cannot send headers in Gd2.php

Tags: php, debugging, magento, header

2012-10-31T10:49:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2.php, line 133

```
2012-10-31T10:49:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php:17239 
[1] /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php:17123 
[2] /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php:17278 
[3] /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php:17490 
[4] /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php:20055 
[5] /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php:683 
[6] /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/index.php:87 
</pre> 
2012-10-31T10:49:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array 
( 
[0] => Array 
( 
[name] => Content-Type 
[value] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 
[replace] => 
)

)
```

When I check the code magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php

```
public function display()
    {
        header(\"Content-type: \".$this->getMimeType());
        call_user_func($this->_getCallback(\'output\'), $this->_imageHandler); // 133 line
    }
```

Isn’t this a BUG?

Who can give more tips how to debug it?

I have added:
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php

```
Mage::log('HEADERS ALREADY SENT: '.mageDebugBacktrace(true, true, true));
```

/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php

```
Mage::Log('Cannot send headers; headers already sent in ' . $file . ', line ' . $line);
```

Then got the error info: /home/happiniess/public_html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2.php, line 133

Now I don't know how to fix it!!!

Help!!!

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? And if so: how?

Answer (score 0):

try it 
For this error

1. Disable compilation and remove cache

I think new added file not complile